# How to select unique columns for two joined tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, select, unique, distinct

I am using SQL Server. I have two tables `employees` and `employees entry times`.

I am joining these tables using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But I want to get the last input value for each employee(Last entered date).

Summary purpose

1. Select all employee. If there is no input value corresponding to employee return null.
2. If there are much input value corresponding, select last entered date

How do I do this?

The problem I'm having is exponentially more complex.

So simplified example for understanding;

Table 1 : Employees

```
Id
Name
```

Table 2 : Employee_Entry_Times

```
Id
Time_Entered
Employee_REFER
```

Comment: Well - show us your query that you already have! And show us sample data, what your query returns currently, and what you *want* to return instead...

Comment: "How to select unique columns for two joined tables" => Sounds like this is what you are chasing after : Select Union 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Unless you update your question to be more specifc.

Comment: You can use either `TOP (1)` in an `APPLY`, or `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
select e.name, MAX(t.Time_Entered)
from 
employees e left outer join Employee_Entry_Times t
on e.id = t.Employee_REFER
group by e.name
```